# Does ECS task definition support volume mapping syntax?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

docker-compose spec support volume mapping syntax under `services`, for example:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    external: true

services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID}
        DOCKER_VERSION: ${DOCKER_VERSION}
        DOCKER_COMPOSE: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE}
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

---

Following `"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09"`, the corresponding ECS task definition has volume syntax un-readable(with `MountPoints` and `Volumes`), as shown below:

```
"EcsTaskDefinition": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "Properties": {
                "ContainerDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "jenkins",
                        "Image": "xyzaccount/jenkins:ecs",
                        "Memory": 995,
                        "PortMappings": [ { "ContainerPort": 8080, "HostPort": 8080 } ],
                        "MountPoints": [
                            {
                                "SourceVolume": "docker",
                                "ContainerPath": "/var/run/docker.sock"
                            },
                            {
                                "SourceVolume": "jenkins_home",
                                "ContainerPath": "/var/jenkins_home"
                            }
                        ]
                    }


                ],
                "Volumes": [
                    {
                        "Name": "jenkins_home",
                        "Host": { "SourcePath": "/ecs/jenkins_home" }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "docker",
                        "Host": { "SourcePath": "/var/run/docker.sock" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

---

Does ECS task definition syntax of CloudFormation (now) support volume mapping syntax? similar to docker-compose....

Comment: It’s usually better to phrase questions positively.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry.. my bad

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course, ECS support docker socket mounting, but the syntax is bit different. Add `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in the task definition and source path should start with `//`.

```
 "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "docker",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "//var/run/docker.sock"
            }
        }
    ]
```

The `//` worked in case of AWS ecs.

Also, you need to add `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in your task definition.

```
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "DOCKER_HOST",
                    "value": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find any documentation about that, but it worked like a charm. Also, I was using CDK to deploy my service instead of directing creating the cloudformation file. Don't forget to add the MountPoints with the same name and sourcePath :)