# docker.sock bind mount AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

What I want to accomplish is the equivalent of :

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker sock <image>`

EDITED:

I followed this: [Does ECS task definition support volume mapping syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096957/does-ecs-task-definition-support-volume-mapping-syntax)

But then it is unable to save because this type of bind mount is not available for [fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate).

Is there another way to accomplish it for [fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the Docker socket from within a container managed by AWS. I guess this is not available. Instead, you need to make API calls to AWS to launch new containers. Maybe something like [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-modern-application-workshop/blob/python/module-2/README.md)? Or probably rethink the whole thing.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be right. I thought it would be easy, but it seems setting it up with a master and slave containers might be easier. And probably better.